# NULL undeclared identifier in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

In my C++/CLI library, I am getting the compiler error:

```
error C2065: 'NULL' : undeclared identifier
```

Why is this happening? Note: I am setting the value of an *unmanaged* pointer to NULL, not a managed clr object pointer.

I know that I could just define `NULL` as 0, but that doesn't answer why this is suddenly happening. I am using `NULL` in other places, and things work fine.

If I add `Windows.h` to my stdafx.h include file, then I get warnings about a mismatch in the stdlib versions being linked with other dlls.

Why am I suddenly having issues using `NULL`?

Also, is it true that I can use `nullptr` for unmanaged types as well as managed?

*EDIT:* It seems that the answer to whether `nullptr` can be used for unmanaged types is yes. So I think that the answer is to just start using `nullptr`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ex65770.aspx

Comment: You can write a *lot* of C++/CLI code without ever #including any of the C library headers.  C++11 now uses `nullptr` but that was already a keyword in C++/CLI, you can use `__nullptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to include stdlin.h or stddef.h, I believe

Comment: I just put that in my stdafx.h file, and that worked. It did not create any stdlib link conflicts, which I have been trying to avoid.

However, why has `NULL` always worked for me before? Seems odd.

Comment: well, I would venture you excluded some header which explicitly or implicitly includes stdlib